# Can be $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\:f_{_n}(x)=x^n \cdot\ e^x$ uniform convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

We have $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\:f_{_n}(x)=x^n \cdot\ e^x$.

I don't know how we can find the pointwise convergence...This sequence can be a uniform convergence? and explain your argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointwise convergence is very simple.

In order for a series of functions $f_n$ to converge pointwise towards a function $f$, the only condition is:

> For all values $x$, the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$$ is equal to $f(x)$

Did you try to calculate the limit in your case? Since $x$ is fixed, it should be easy!

Comment: is $e^x$ which confuse me

Comment: I suppose if was not $e^x$  the pointwise convergence will be 0

Comment: @Lucas But for each fixed $x$, $e^x$ is just a number. Also, the convergence is not $0$ for $x=1$. But for $x<1$, you have $x^ne^x$, and when $n$ becomes large, $x^n$ comes close to $0$, and $e^x$ remains fixed...

Comment: so we'll have $0 \cdot\ e^x$ and which is the pointwise convergence? is not 0? because you say $e^x$ is fixed

Comment: @Lucas You phrased that strangely. I would say that for every $x<1$, the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ is equal to $0$. However, you have to check $x=1$ separately!

Comment: it is for check if have uniforme convergence but first step I ask if the pointwise convergence is 0, and is it

Comment: @Lucas I don't know, is the pointwise convergence $0$ for $x=1$? Did you try to see what the limit is for $x=1$?

Comment: for $x=1$ we obtain $e$

Comment: @Lucas So, what is the pointwise limit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23246/discussion-between-lucas-and-5xum).

Comment: hmmm, will be $e$

Comment: @Lucas the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is a function $f$. I am asking you what this function is.

Comment: the function is $0$, wtf am I wrong?

Comment: @Lucas No. The function $f(x)=0$ does not satisfy the condition $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$$ for **ALL VALUES** $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: wtf... is not a pointwise, I think if $x\in \left(0,1\right)$ than will work and will be 0

Comment: @Lucas Yes, it will. But there also exists a function $f$ which is a pointwise limit of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$. The function is not continuous, though, because it is equal to $0$ on $[0,1)$ and equal to $e$ for $x=1$.

Comment: so we don't know which is the fixed function and when you asked me "what this function is"  I don't know what to say, because for x between $[0,1)$ we obtain $f(x)=0$ which is not equal for $x=1$ and that means is not a pointwise convergence for all values

Comment: @Lucas Of course we do, the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x<1\\ e & x=1\end{cases}$$ fits nicely.

Comment: I think even if $f_n$ was defined on $[0,1)$, don't have uniform convergence

Comment: @Lucas You are correct.

Answer (score -1):

**Pointwise convergence** for any $x\in [0,1)$ we have $x^ne^x\to 0$ and $f_n(1)\to e$ so the sequence has a non continuous pointwise limit and therefore the sequence **cannot be uniformly convergent**